# Input string and Search it inside a file Python

Tags: python

I am a newbie I am trying to implement a code where if I type text it will look inside the file and will say if there's something matched or not if doesn't matched anything it will display no record however this below code is not giving the right output  any idea thank you very much in advance

```
  input = raw_input("Input Text you want to search: ")
  with open('try.txt') as f:
      found = False
      if input in f: 
         print "true"
         found = True
         if not found:
            print('no record!')
```

Comment: This won't even run because the indentation doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to match a string against the text from the file, you need to read the file:

```
with open('try.txt') as f:
    data = f.read()
```

Then to check if a string is found in the file, check like this:

```
if input_ in data:
    pass
```

Also, two tips:

1) Indent your code correctly. Use four spaces for every level of indentation.

2) Don't use reserved keywords to name your variables. Instead of input, use input_ or something else.

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually reading the file, try something like `file_content = f.read()` and then do a `if input in file_content`.

Answer (score 0):

This should print "true" if found or "no record!" for not found 
I've not included your boolean "found" variable because it's not used.
First the file data is read into "data" variable as a string then we perform a check with in operator

```
input = raw_input("Input Text you want to search: ")

with open('try.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    data=myfile.read()

if input in data:
    print "true"
else:
    print('no record!')
```